# Deploying NodeJS project to Web App-config.js breaks due to gitignore (?)

Tags: node.js, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

I have a NodeJS server project running fine locally. Connection variables are stored in a config.js file. This file is included in my gitignore. The code is written in such a way as to primarily use system environmental variables, and if those do not appear, pull from config.js.

I have set up an Azure web app with continuous integration through our Git repository. The app is deploying fine, but obviously without config.js.

API calls to the app are returning a 404 error. Looking at the diagnostic logs, I'm seeing the request coming through properly, and errors like this:

`Buffer="The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."`

I am not seeing any more detail than that, and not sure how I can get details. I assumed that what is causing the error is requiring the config file, which is obviously being ignored by git, and thus not making it to the web app. However, when I remove the import statements and the references to config.js, the error persists.

So, two questions:

1) How do I test this hypothesis in a more systematic way than just trial and error?

2) How do I avoid such errors in the future?

Comment: Did you try running locally without that file? That would result verify that theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, got a good answer via Stephen Grider's excellent [Node+React course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/node-with-react-fullstack-web-development). Basically, you need three files: a config file which imports one of two other files based on the environment (production or not). Those two files export objects with identical keys, but values which are either pulled from the environment (in production) or hard-wired (in dev.) The dev file is listed in gitignore. Then, in the rest of your app, just import or require config.js and use the keys from there.

It looks like this:

config.js:

```
if (process.env.node_ENV === 'production')
{
    module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

prod.js:

```
module.exports = {
    secret: process.env.JWT_KEY,
    conn: process.env.COSMOS_CONN,
    sgKey: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
    googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
};
```

dev.js:

```
module.exports = {
    secret: 'xyz',
    conn: '123',
    sgKey: 'sdsddf',
    googleClientID: 'ddcxcx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    googleClientSecret: 'dcvccfssfdas'
};
```